# AS3 how to go to next frame in Main Timeline when character die animation ends

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

so I need to know if my character(bird) hitTestObject with pipe he plays the die animation after the animation ends it need to go to the game over frame in the main timeline

(this code is in the main timeline layer Actions)

```
if (bird.hitTestObject(pipe1)) {

 bird.gotoAndStop(3); //frame 3 = where the die animation is 

}
```

LINK 1 (here you see different frames for animations frame 3 is die animation)
http://gyazo.com/67381832827bfb8a4dac2452076a4217

LINK 2 (the die animation) 
http://gyazo.com/bf5153a9d00e1478471fff7b73d0c592

so here you can see the animation in the end of the animation there need code to go to game over frame in the main timeline frame 3

btw its not in a .as file but in the timeline

thank you if you can help me and if my english is not good sorry about that im dutch

Answer (score 0):

You can add enterframe listener and check if animation is complete. Something like that in 3rd frame:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


var dieClip:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("Snail123fall");
//not sure what's the name of your clip but I assume it's something like that
//if your die animation clip has no name set than name it like that or any way 
//you want and use this name here

dieClip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame)   

private function handleEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
{
    if(dieClip.currentFrame == dieClip.totalFrames)
    {
        this.gotoAndStop(4);//game over frame       
    }
}
```